# c# how do i set entire worksheet to ignored errors=true code

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have done all the work to add the data and the formulas to worksheet.  Excel find errors when it opens that I do not want user to see.  I do not want user to have to go to cell and right the prompt ignore errors.  I do not want background error check to run when the file opens.  I have checked all the errors already what is there I want to be there.

```
 worksheet.Append(sheetFormatProperties1);
 worksheet.Append(columns1);
 worksheet.Append(sheetData);
 worksheet.Append(mergeCells1);
 worksheet.Append(conditionalFormatting1);
 worksheet.Append(pageMargins1);

worksheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;
```

can I set background error checking off here? or

```
errors.ignore = true
```

I cannot find the syntax  to attach to either

```
worksheetPart.Worksheet

spreadsheetDocument.Close();
```

I have seen this one

```
<ignoredErrors>  
  <ignoredError sqref="A1 B2" numberStoredAsText="1"/>  
</ignoredErrors>
```

but I do not know how to implement in my C# code?  Company will not let me use EPPlus

Cindy